# NodeJS create a function that returns document from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm not sure if this is possible but I am using NodeJS and I'm trying to create a function that would return a document from MongoDB. My code currently looks like this but returns undefined:

```
const GetUser = (userId) => {
    let userData
    
    User.aggregate([
        { $match: {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)} },
        { 
             $project: {
                  "_id": 0,
                  "originId": 1,
                  "type": 1,
                  "poster": 1,
                  "content": 1,
                  "createdAt": 1,
                  "updatedAt" : 1
             }
        }
    ]).exec((err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            return err
        }
        else {
            userData = res
        }
    })

    return userData
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this. You just return your aggregation query it returns an promise.

```
const GetUser = userId => {
  let userData;
  return User.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        originId: 1,
        type: 1,
        poster: 1,
        content: 1,
        createdAt: 1,
        updatedAt: 1
      }
    }
  ]);
};
```

I am not sure if you need the `.exec()` here but however you can try it with and without.

Later you can use your function like this:

Because its an promise, you can use `.then()` on it:

```
GetUser(id).then(response => {
   console.log(response)
})
```

or if you use it in an `async` function :

```
let user = await GetUser(id);
console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ifaruki's solution is correct. But just to visualize your problem:

```
const GetUser = (userId) => {
  let userData 
  
  // This will start the aggregation, but...
  User.aggregate( ... ).exec((err, res) => {
      // The callback will run sometime in the future.
      userData = res

      // Even if you could return something here, it's too late,
      // the parent function's return has already happened
  })
  
  // here "userData = res"  has not happened yet. It's still undefined.
  return userData
}
```

The best you can get is to return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You must have **return userData** inside else below **userData = res**,

exec is asynchronous so before it gets executed your function returns.

```
    const GetUser = (userId) => {
    let userData
    
    User.aggregate([
        { $match: {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)} },
        { 
             $project: {
                  "_id": 0,
                  "originId": 1,
                  "type": 1,
                  "poster": 1,
                  "content": 1,
                  "createdAt": 1,
                  "updatedAt" : 1
             }
        }
    ]).exec((err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            return err
        }
        else {
            userData = res
            return userData
        }
    })
}
```

caveat:- I am believing your database has a value that your query returns data for.

Comment: that dont work, you returning your data in an callback function

Comment: why not? you can return your data from wherever you want.

Comment: it doesnt make sense to return your data to an callback arrow function , he will still get undefined

Comment: it will work if data is present. If you are working with callbacks that's how you return. Solving it with Promise and/or (asyn/await) is a clean option.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ifaruki/pen/MWyKJNO?editors=1111 a little example. if you open the console, you can see that the data is present but the function still returns undefined

Comment: in your codepen example, there is a conceptual mistake, your test method itself returns a callback, so you cannot directly access what it returns, if you add a callback on test function you will get data, like this at bottom


test(a => {
  console.log(a);
})

Comment: `so you cannot directly access what it returns` yes, thats exactly the problem what you have in your code. if he calls `GetUser(id)` he will still get undefined

Comment: I believe it is expected behaviour getuserid returns callback, even with promise approach one will need .then or await keywords.